# Failed to connect to remote VM using Glassfish and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, glassfish, localhost

i'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Eclipse Kepler.

Glassfish configuration:

`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009`.

Debug: Enabled

Into Eclipse, in the Remote Java Application i've selected the project, and in the connection properties i've set:

Host: localhost

port: 9009

When i try to connect the debug, the message error is:

Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect

I've checked the port 9009 with a telnet,  and is not used...

can someone help me?

tx

Comment: localhost is not remote.

Comment: but i want to connect to my machine..

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] it's a problem with the glassfish plugin in Eclipse! you must to start glassfish form the command line, not from the Eclipse window. After, you can connect like remote debug to your local glassfish ;)

Answer (score 0):

In **Host**, you need to give **IP** address of the remote machine you want to connect.

**localhost** is your own machine.